# How to correctly use typing for a sort key function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, typing

For this sort key method:

```
def srt(self,r:Optional[Colour])->Optional[int]:
  if not isinstance(r,Colour):
    return None
  return r.index
```

used in a later method in the same class (NOT Colour):

```
items=sorted(self.__dict__.values(),key=self.srt)
```

results in this error from mypy:

```
error: Argument "key" to "sorted" has incompatible type "Callable[[Optional[Colour]], Optional[int]]"; expected "Callable[[Any], SupportsLessThan]"  [arg-type]
```

I can make it shut up by either forcing srt() to the signature it wants, or by doing a type: ignore on the call to sorted. But I'd rather do it right.

I'm clearly doing something wrong, but what?  Even if there is no good way to do this, I want to know why mypy is complaining.

Comment: Why does `srt` accept an optional argument? `sorted` always passes the item it's sorting to the `key`. Also why is the return optional? That would cause `sorted` to break if it ever encountered a `None` key, since you can't compare integers with `None`

Comment: Plus, `self.__dict__` could have pretty much anything in it, especially in subclasses. Trying to sort `self.__dict__.values()` is probably the wrong approach in the first place.

Comment: This is catching an *actual* bug in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a function that returns `Optional[int]` but a function is required that returns `SupportsLessThan`. `Optional[int]` does not support "less than", because `None` cannot be compared to any `int`.

What *does* support "less than" is just `int`. So you could change the return type of your function to `int` and make it return some integer in the special case that `r` is not a `Colour`, instead of `None`.

*Which* integer it should return in this case depends on what you are trying to achieve. Possibly you could return `-1` in case you want any non-`Colour` values to be sorted before any `Colour` values, since that would be smaller than any value of `r.index` (at least that's what I expect from something called "index").

Comment: srt() accepts an Optional argument because it used to be, in the days of the dunder cmp method, that the compare() function would get Nones passed in, so we had to allow for that. I'm happy to learn that's no longer the case.  I'll change the signature.

Comment: The argument that `srt` receives can still be `None`, it just can't return `None`.